# Is "Whom should I give this job to?" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, whom

I found [**a grammar rule**](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/whoVwhom.asp) about when to choose "who" and "whom".

> Rule. Use this he/him method to decide whether who or whom is correct:
>
> he = who
>
> him = whom

So I have a question about correctness of the following question:

> Who should I give this job to?

According to this rule we should have used *whom* instead of *who*, because *I should give this job to **him***, not *I should give this job to **he***. But there's a man who keeps telling me that

> Whom should I give this job to?

is wrong. Please clarify?

Comment: "Whom" is correct. It is the proper usage of the objective pronoun. Although the term is currently in flux, it is desirable--at least in my humble opinion--that the "formal" or, perhaps more appropriately, historically correct form be used wherever possible. In that case, "whom."

Answer (score 8):

In modern colloquial English, "who" is always okay.  In your example, you have correctly applied the rule for old-fashioned and formal English -- it would be "Whom should I give the job to?", or perhaps better (in that style): "To whom should I give the job?"  (But "To who should I give the job?" sounds wrong.)

Comment: Hi, Greg, I think your answer, "In modern colloquial English, "who" is always okay." could be a little misleading even though I fully understand what you mean. Why not change it to "... always okay except that it follows a preposition"?

Comment: @Rathony, Okay, I added a note about this.  However, I think in some circumstances "to who" sounds pretty good.  If someone tells you to give a book away, you could ask, "To who?"

Comment: Great. I just upvoted your answer. To who sounds correct. So there is no hard and fast rule. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Greg pointed the right solution : By using ***to* whom**, you must put "whom". 
In US colloquial speech we use who for whom & it's fine. But here, "To whom" sounds the best version.

Plus, this "Whom" is object to receive the job, so as it is not active, it should not be "Who" whatever we may say today.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose the tag "whom" you'll find about 50 posts about the topic whom or who. "whom" is the normal accusative but language is changing and in spoken language the m of whom is dropped due to the fact that in English nominative and accusative have the same form with the exception of a handful of personal pronouns (special accusatives: me him her us them). And in written language whom is becoming formal.

Answer (score -1):

Indeed, to make it easier now, we use *who* for *whom* except in cases with subordonate or complex constructions which are not always found in formal speech : "A pom pom girl gets in then sees the WR with *whom* she has an affair". But if you'd use nominative for accusative, *who* for *whom* : beware !
"A receiver on who the QB can rely" is **wrong** ; as it must be *on whom* even with relatives because a preposition is preceding the object.

Comment: Do you need to write another post to answer the same question? Why not edit your previous answer?

Comment: Yes Rathony, because the 2nd post is dealing about complex constructions ; the 1st. one was for direct speech.

Comment: The poster didn't ask about who/whom in a complex sentence. The question is about the **interrogative pronoun** who/whom, not the **relative pronoun** who/whom.

Comment: I also understood the question but Greg wrote "who" is ALWAYS okay ; so I thought we had to make this precision  in a 2nd post.